# Python3: ValueError: invalid variable 'py_version_nodot_plat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install on cmd/windows10 this library:

```
py -m pip install PyExecJS
```

I get this message,

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Castel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-olb4pmo_\\pyexecjs_d890f61241754a86b05696cc575c0ff6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Castel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-olb4pmo_\\pyexecjs_d890f61241754a86b05696cc575c0ff6\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hnlq7en9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\PyExecJS' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please read the complete error message here:

https://pastebin.com/BeSV9Fyz

Comment: Try installing wheel first with `pip install wheel` and then `PyExecJS`. Also, are you sure, this is supported in 3.10 ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing this:

`py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

or

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`